# Desktop not hardware compatible with 3D effects

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

When I try to install 11.04 on my desktop machine, I get a notification that my system is not hardware compatible for 3D effects and that I should run "Classic Gnome," but even under classic gnome my system doesn't seem to be able to run "Natty." Any ideas, or should I just break down and buy a new Video Card? The system can run 10.10 without any issues (i386)

Comment: Rob - please add to your question the video card you have and if you have activated any additional hardware drivers.  Also, please clarify what you mean "system doesnt seem to be able to run Natty" when using classic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered Unity 2D while "surfing,"http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/unity-2d-qt-now-available-in-ppa-for.html: (This is the link to how to install "Unity 2D." Canonical might want to consider offering Unity 2D as an installation option in Natty for those of us running "legacy" systems!)